# problem set 2 CS50, creating a counter to count only letters on readability, very new to coding

Tags: c, cs50

Really struggling to solve this error, I think it is to do with declaring isalpha incorrectly but thats all I can think of, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Error**

```
readability.c:5:18: error expected ')' 
int isalpha(char c);
                 ^
readability.c:5:5: note: to match this '('
int isalpha(char c);
    ^    
/usr/include/ctype.h:190:31 note: expanded from macro 'isalpha'
```

**Code**

```
`int isalpha(char c);

int main(void);

{   int length = 0;
    string text = get_string("text: ");
    for (int i = 0;  text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            length++;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Is that really the code you compile? Don't you have any `#include` directives above? In that case you should get some other warnings but not this error. Please show exact code, not something different.

Comment: When asking other people for help, never show an error message that does not match the code. In `readability.c:5:18: error expected ')' `, the `5` means line 5, but `int isalpha(char c);` is not on line 5 in the code you show. Always prepare a [mre], and then you compile the [mre], which contains the code you are going to show people, and you show them the error messages from exactly the code you paste into the question, not the error messages from the code you have on your computer that you are not showing completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `isalpha` is defined as a macro in `ctype.h`:

```
# define isalpha(c) __isctype((c), _ISalpha)
```

That's why you cannot write the prototype of the function in your code.

It would have been the wrong prototype anyhow, the correct one would be `int isalpha(int);`. The function takes the character as an `int`, not a `char`.

To solve your problem: Remove the line `int isalpha(char c);`. The error message hints that you already have `#include <ctype.h>` above the shown code snippet.

There is also a trailing `;` at the line `int main(void);`, which you have to remove.

https://godbolt.org/z/q1cWKj1ns

Comment: I have some doubts that this error message can be raised unless the header is included already.

Comment: @Gerhardh There is a different error message when the header is not included, something like wrong prototype for `isalpha`.

Comment: Yes, therefore the suggestion to include `ctype.h` does not make sense as it must be already there. As a sidenote: You could declara a function: `int (isalpha)(int c);` This would not be replaced using the macro definition from the header. But that wouldn't be very useful I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Agree; error message indicates line 5 so code example is incomplete. Still, isalpha() is generally implemented as a macro so no prototype is needed. Should be int islpha(int c); anyway.

Comment: That should go into a comment, not in an answer.